# Terraform modules azure event subscription optional fields

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to work with terraform modules to create event subscription pointing to storage queue as an endpoint to it.

Below is the module

```
  resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "events" {
  name                      = var.name
  scope                     = var.scope
  subject_filter            = var.subject_filter
  storage_queue_endpoint    = var.storage_queue_endpoint
  }
```

and terraform is

```
module "storage_account__event_subscription" {
  source       = "../modules/event"
  name         = "testevent"
  scope        = test
  subject_filter = {
    subject_begins_with = "/blobServices/default/containers/test/blobs/in"
  }

  storage_queue_endpoint = {
    storage_account_id = test
    queue_name         = test
  }
}
```

Error message:

> > :   subject_filter {
> >     Blocks of type "subject_filter" are not expected here.
> >     Error: Unsupported block type
> >     on azure.tf line 90, in module "storage_account__event_subscription":
> >      :   storage_queue_endpoint {
> >     Blocks of type "storage_queue_endpoint" are not expected here.

How do i parse the optional fields properly in terraform modules ?

Answer (score 0):

In you module:

```
  resource "azurerm_eventgrid_event_subscription" "events" {
  name                      = var.name
  scope                     = var.scope
  subject_filter            = {
    subject_begins_with = var.subject_begins_with
}
  storage_queue_endpoint    = var.storage_queue_endpoint
  }
```

Formatting is off here so make sure to run `terraform fmt` to account for my poor formatting. Also add the variable to the `variables.tf` file.

Your Terraform file:

```
module "storage_account__event_subscription" {
  source       = "../modules/event"
  name         = "testevent"
  scope        = test
  subject_begins_with = "/blobServices/default/containers/test/blobs/in"

  storage_queue_endpoint = {
    storage_account_id = test
    queue_name         = test
  }
}
```

You create the full structure in the module and then you assign the variables in the terraform file.

Anything that will have the same, or generally the same, value can have a default value set in the `variables.tf` as well so that you get smaller chunks in the TF file.